# Error while trying Webservice

Tags: apex, webservices

[image: This is the error i am getting in webservice]

Hello Guys,

I am learning Webservice but I am getting this error ::Error: Compile Error: Argument type of global method must also be global: Account at line 2 column 26

I am following the salesforce documentation [Salesforce Apex Document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods.htm), If they have given it in document it means code is proper. 
Is there any problem with my Developer Edition ? I even tried deactivating the triggers  but it's not working .

Comment: Do you have a class in your org called 'Account' incidentally?

Comment: Yes... I have....

Comment: Once I delete the Account Class I able to save the webservice class..Thanks for pointing out.. By the way why I was getting that Error ? any clue...

Comment: This is called [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Your type was not [fully qualified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) and the compiler sees `namespace.Account` (class type) instead of `Schema.Account` (sobject type), as you created a class with that name.

Comment: @user320 your comment solved my problem but i will select -sfdcfox- answer as Accepted answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a class named `Account`. Unless that class is global, it would not be accessible to the Web Service method.

```
public class Account { /* Cannot be a parameter in a web service */ }

global class Account { /* Can be a parameter in a web service */ }
```

If you specify a class name that mimics a system object (e.g. Account, Contact), then you must explicitly use the `Schema` namespace to reference the standard object. The following code will work regardless of the presence of an Account class:

```
global class MyWebService {
    webservice static Id makeContact(String lastName, Schema.Account a) {
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Weissman', AccountId=a.Id);
        insert c;
        return c.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you get a sec @sfdcfox can you make some trivial edit to this answer to unlock votes? rgds

Comment: @user320 As you wish!